# How do I determine what pieces of vinyl siding to buy?

Tags: vinyl-siding, siding

My house has vinyl siding.  I am considering installing vinyl siding on a shed also.  How do I find siding to match what I already have on my house?  (It is only a year or two old, but installed by the previous owner.)  Can I expect to find what I need at the local Lowe's or Home Depot, or are many brands of vinyl siding only sold by specialty retailers or directly to contractors?

Looking at my house, there seem to be a lot of different pieces: regular, top, and bottom boards; corner pieces; special pieces around doors, windows, sillcocks, and electrical outlets; and so on.  How do I find out what pieces I need?  Is that particular to each manufacturer?

Comment: I voted to close as not a real question as it's difficult to tell what's really being asked here. I'd suggest revising this to be a more refined and targetted question.

Comment: @Mike, why do you say it's not a real question?  I'm considering getting vinyl siding for my shed in order to make it match my house, and because I grew up in Scandinavia where vinyl siding is considered cheap and tacky (my dad told me after I bought this house that it looks like a yogurt cup!), I have no idea where to start.  How would you suggest changing my question to make it more targeted?

Comment: I'm just being overly cautious about the quality of questions. If the community agrees, they'll vote to close too. With that said, I would suggest either making this a community wiki, or focusing on one of the four questions you ask here. "how do I find siding to match what I already have" is a good one. I'd also remove the "is it straightforward" bit.

Comment: I'm glad this question wasn't closed. I'm in exactly the same boat and would have phrased my question similarly.

Answer (score 2):

If you can remove one panel carefully you might find the manufacturer stamp on the back. It will narrow down the search down a little bit. Otherwise just a small sample would be nice to have when visit the stores. I've seen websites on the web that identify manufactures based on the sample that you send. Both Lowe's and Home Depot sell some vynil siding. Not a huge selection.

Honestly, it doesn't have to be exactly the same. The previous owner used a similar siding on the addition and i didn't notice until i had to replace a panel.

Answer (score 1):

Generally big box stores sell very limited selection of vinyl siding, and it's not quality stuff.  Just because the manufacturers prefer to deal with contractors directly and they don't sell to the general public.  Your best bet is to pry off a piece of siding from the house, there is a tool for that, and look for manufacturer's stamp/color code/name, and go from there.  Or just match the color to what you find in stores the best you can.